# QlikView Set Analysis: use either column number or other unique info from row

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to use Set Analysis in the table below for the column labelled test.  I am trying to get `sum([Best Dollar])` for the date range specified by the `Start` and `End` columns.

This expression returns results, but it's naturally static for each row of the table:

```
=sum({$<AsAtDate={">=40959 and <=40960"}>} [Best Dollar])/1000
```

This is what I want to have but it returns 0:

```
=Sum({$<AsAtDate={">=(num(floor(BroadcastWeekStart2))) and <=(num(floor(BroadcastWeekStart2)))+6"}>} [Best Dollar])/1000
```

To obtain unique start date serial numbers for each line for the start column (`BroadcastWeekStart2`) I use the following expression:

```
=(num(floor(BroadcastWeekStart2)))
```

How can I specify that the values or calculations used for the start and end columns are used in Set Analysis for the field above?

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one information missing in your question.

Do you want to select on fixed values or should the `sum` depend on the current time?

For the static version something like

```
=sum( {$<BroadcastWeekStart2={"40959"}, BroadcastWeekStart2={"<=40960"}>} [Best Dollar])/1000
```

should work. (Assuming that **BroadcastWeekStart2** contains these kind of values.)

Let me show you an example how I calculate values for the current week:

```
='Count: ' & count({$<start_week={"$(=WeekStart(Today()))"}>} Games)
```

where the **start_week** is set in the load script by:

WeekStart(date#(@4, 'YYYYMMDD')) as start_week,